# Get next value from Cursor in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have `Option` table which contains number of rows based on `Question`. So I want to display options in row wise. I also want `onClick()` event to check whether `Option` is right or wrong.

**My Table is as below:** Answer 1 means Right answer, 0 means Wrong answer.

```
Option     QId      Answer
test1       1         0
test2       1         1
test3       1         0
test4       1         0
```

**My Code is as below :**

```
public Cursor getOptions(String QId) {
        try {
            String sql = "Select * from tblOptions Where QId=" + QId + "";

            Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
            if (mCur != null) {
                mCur.moveToNext();
            }
            return mCur;
        } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getOptions >>" + mSQLException.toString());
            throw mSQLException;
        }
    }
ConnectionAdapter dbCon = new ConnectionAdapter(this);
        dbCon.createDatabase();
        dbCon.open();

        Cursor question = dbCon.getQuestion();
        Cursor option = dbCon.getOptions(Utility
                .GetColumnValue(question, "QId"));

        dbCon.close();
        // SaveUserResponse();
        String Question = question.getString(question
                .getColumnIndex("Question"));

        tvNote.setText(Question);

        String Options = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < option.getCount(); i++) {
            Options = Options + Utility.GetColumnValue(option, "Option");
            option.moveToNext();
        }

        tvRQOption.setText(Options);
```

`tvRQOption` is showing me only test4. What I am doing wrong ? And what should I do to check right or wrong option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Cursor getOptions(String QId) {
        try {
            String sql = "Select * from tblOptions Where QId=" + QId + "";

            Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);


        } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getOptions >>" + mSQLException.toString());
            throw mSQLException;
        }
    }
```

Getting values from db

```
Cursor cursor = db_obj.getoptions("Your_id")
{
 cursor.moveToFirst();
   if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) 
   {
       String string = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Column_Name"));
       //Set this String value to Ui i.e your option
       cursor.moveToNext(); 
   }
}
```

Comment: had you set string value to your ui before cursor.moveToNext() ?